# Converting 1.7 Subversion repository to Mercurial

Tags: svn, mercurial

I have a SVN repository with the new 1.7 Subversion working copy format (centralized metadata). I am trying to convert it to Mercurial using the following command:

```
hg convert --source-type=svn --dest-type=hg --authors=authors.txt Prodigio Capi
```

(where Prodigio is the folder containing the SVN repo and Capi is an empty folder where I want the Hg repo to be saved)

I had previously used this command and it worked fine. However, since I upgraded my working copy to the new format (using the latest TortoiseSVN, 1.7.2), I get this error:

```
initializing destination Capi repository
file:///D:/SVN/Prodigio does not look like a Subversion repository
abort: D:\SVN\Prodigio: missing or unsupported repository
```

I am running Windows 7 x64 and I have TortoiseHg 2.2.1 installed. I also have Collabnet's command-line subversion client 1.7.1 installed, although it's not in my executable path.

I believe the problem is that Mercurial is using an outdated version of SVN. Any clues on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest workaround is probably to just pass the SVN repo URL to hg convert, which convert should recognize and use. I think that the convert extension actually has its own logic to detect svn working copies, and that might need updating, so it may have nothing to do with the svn libraries in use by Mercurial.